# VB6 file losing its secure certificate validation when executed from another program

Tags: vb6, certificate, signing

I have a small VB6 exe file that I have signed using a code signing certificate from GoDaddy.
I signed the file using Micrsoft's SignTool.
I put the file on a Windows PC and execute it. No problem. Certificate is valid.
I can run it multiple times, and still valid.

I then I have another program (Access DB) that calls this file using a shell command.
Once it calls that file, it immediately makes the file's certificate invalid: "The Digital Signature Is Invalid"

This VB6 file has never been a problem for years.  I recently had to make a small change to the file. Just one line of code.

I'm stumped.

Note: The VB6 file performs on FTP file download.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are looking at which shows the cert as invalid? Also, does the actual EXE file get changed in some way? Or is it unmodified after the call from Access?

Comment: The file is not modified. It is just passed a command line argument.

Comment: I check the Cert by looking at the file's properties, then selecting the 'Digital Signature' tab, then select the name of signer, then click 'details'. It will normally say 'This Digital Signature Is OK' . When called from Access VBA it then says. "This certificate is not valid"